# How to configure separately both RabbitMQ consumer and producer in a spring boot app on a different port

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

Is is possible to configure springboot application to connect to consumer on one port and producer on the other, using the same/single RabbitMQ docker instance running locally.